# Execute .exe in WSL works in Windows itself, but not if SSH into it

Tags: ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In WSL/Ubuntu, I could open/run an executable by:

```
user@desktop: notepad.exe
```

This will open up the notepad. However, if I ssh into the WSL from other client, like from iPad, typing that command return an error saying:

```
command not found
```

Any idea why is that? Is this something that achievable? Thanks!

Comment: Set up your PATH properly for the ssh client users

Comment: I did that, by `export PATH=$PATH:/mnt/c/Windows/System32` and then run the command, the client would just freeze and do nothing until I cancelled it.

Comment: You need to run an editor that supports remote display ...

Answer (score 0):

it isn't possible because notepad uses windows display server but ssh clients expect X Server.

you can install something like gedit instead of notepad that supports X Server forwarding.

then you can ssh into server using

```
ssh -Y user@host
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this command before trying to run the program

```
su <username> -
```

I had a similar problem when trying to run powershell or cmd when using ssh remotely. Running powershell directly from its folder just resulted in the session hanging with no way to cancel out. The problem is something with your environment.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that when I set up sshd on a wsl system (host) and ssh into it from a windows 10 system (client) using the ssh command in client-cmd and then try to get access to a host-cmd using `/mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe`, my client froze.

But when I start a wsl session on the client as well, and connect the host from there, no freez happens and I can access the host-cmd.

So it seems that the linux (ubuntu) version of openssh works, but the windows version wont.

Fun fact: If a get cmd access on the host as described above and type `notepad.exe`, notepad opens on the host with a gui.

Answer (score 0):

When you know the exact path, you can execute with "command":

```
command /mnt/c/windows/system32/ipconfig.exe
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).